# Cut out Parts from a div

Tags: css, css-shapes

[Here](https://codepen.io/dhruvsinghal/pen/ZyZQRv?editors=0100) I have tried to make Indian Flag. I just want to cut out

```
html > body > .flag > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:after
```

and

```
html > body > .flag > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:before
```

from

```
html > body > .flag > div:nth-child(2) > div
```

so that middle Ashok Chakra is Formed… Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: Why not take it as SVG?

Comment: we can do anything with svg... It won't be challenging at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete HTML/CSS to create Indian flag (content copied based on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ergtin/pen/bZQbBj)).

You can change `.flag` `font-size` to alter flag size. Also if you are using CSS preprocessor classes from `.spoke1` to `.spoke24` can be moved to preprocessor loop. Here is demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.flag {
  font-size: 6px;
  width: 90em;
  height: 60em;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.stripe {
  height: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stripe1 {
  background-color: #FF9933;
}

.stripe2 {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.stripe3 {
  background-color: #138808;
}

.ashok {
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1em solid navy;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ashok:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.5em;
  left: 6.5em;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: navy;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spoke {
  width: 1em;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.75em;
  left: 8em;
  border-top: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-right: 2em solid navy;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0.25em;
}

.spoke:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: -0.25em;
  left: 3em;
  border-top: 0.25em solid transparent;
  border-left: 5em solid navy;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid transparent;
}

.spoke:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  top: 0.66em;
  left: 7.6em;
  background-color: navy;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spoke1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.spoke2 {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.spoke3 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.spoke4 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.spoke5 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.spoke6 {
  transform: rotate(75deg);
}

.spoke7 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.spoke8 {
  transform: rotate(105deg);
}

.spoke9 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.spoke10 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.spoke11 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.spoke12 {
  transform: rotate(165deg);
}

.spoke13 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.spoke14 {
  transform: rotate(195deg);
}

.spoke15 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.spoke16 {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.spoke17 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.spoke18 {
  transform: rotate(255deg);
}

.spoke19 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.spoke20 {
  transform: rotate(285deg);
}

.spoke21 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.spoke22 {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.spoke23 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

.spoke24 {
  transform: rotate(345deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">
  <div class="stripe stripe1"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe2">
    <div class="ashok">
      <div class="spoke spoke1"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke2"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke3"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke4"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke5"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke6"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke7"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke8"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke9"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke10"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke11"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke12"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke13"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke14"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke15"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke16"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke17"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke18"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke19"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke20"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke21"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke22"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke23"></div>
      <div class="spoke spoke24"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stripe stripe3"></div>
</div>
```